In R/arrow package, function read_csv_arrow show error Invalid: CSV parser got out of sync with chunker
In R/arrow package, function read_csv_arrow show error message Invalid: CSV parser got out of sync with chunker . How to fix it ?
 library(arrow)
    arrow_table <-read_csv_arrow("sample.csv")


use parse_options to set newlines_in_values to True ; look here : https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/CsvReadOptions.html

@Nir Graham  Thanks，   read_csv_arrow can work now after adding 【parse_options = csv_parse_options(newlines_in_values = TRUE)】
